# Mesh text individual letters change colors

Tags: mesh, objects

Is it possible once you change a single text object to mesh, change each word a different colors within the key frames. I thought you could just select the word change the colors within the key frame. Unfortunately, this changes the entire text no matter which word I choose. Any help is appreciated. Using Blender 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from Vers 2.77 here but 2.8+ should be the same or very similar...

Once you've changed your text to mesh you should be able to do that at least two ways -

1:

In edit mode select only those faces on the word(s) you wish to re-colour.
Assign them a new material slot and change it's colour.

2:

In edit mode, select the vertices in only the word(s) you wish to re-colour,
Part them from the mesh with "P".

Return to Object mode and select the words as a separate mesh and give it a new material slot if it hasn't got one already.  Colour it as required.

Parent the new mesh to the main text body if it's to be moved.

Colours can be changed with keyframes as with any other animation.

Answer (score 0):

@Edgel3D

#2 worked.

I could get it to work by selecting each word then using "P" which takes each word and makes it a separate object. This is the same result if I were to type each word individually then put it together. There is a huge positive of the "P" method. Typing it all out at once, you now know each letter/word is exactly were you want it. No lining up different words to make it look like it's one sentence.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  You're right.  I use the 'P' method to have certain words and even single letters to comically fall from signs and text.